# How to calculate (standardized) orthogonal contrast coding in R?

Tags: r, experiment-design, contrasts, fractional-factorial

I want to determine efficient fractional factorial designs and blocked designs for factorial surveys and am using the R library *AlgDesign*. The criteria I'm using to determine if a design is efficient enough is the D-efficiency. In order to get a better understanding how efficient my designs are, I want the D-efficiency to be in the range of 0 to 1.

I've read in literature that this can be achieved by using (standardized) orthogonal contrast coding for my factors. This works fine and I'm getting D-efficiencies in the desired range, that I can easily interpret. What I'm doing is replacing the contrasts for my factors in R by the contrast matrix given in the literature [for example [Kuhfeld (1994)](https://www.sawtoothsoftware.com/download/techpap/1997Proceedings.pdf#page=85)]:

```
lang<-as.factor(c("English","Chinese","Korean","German"))
contrasts(lang)
contrastmatrixlang<-cbind(cbind(c(1.414215,0,0,-1.414214), c(-0.816497,1.632993,0,-0.816497)),c(-0.57735,-0.57735,1.73205,-0.57735)) # orthogonal coding for 4-level factors, see Kuhfeld 1997
contrasts(lang)<-contrastmatrixlang
```

However providing the standardized orthogonal contrast coding like this is somewhat problematic since I can only find these codings for a maximum of five-level factors. So if I want to use a six-level factor (or higher), I don't know what contrast coding to use. Does anyone know a way to calculate these standardized orthogonal contrast codings? Or is there another way to choose contrasts in a way that help me to get d-efficiencies in the desired range?

A full example of what I'm doing atm below:

```
lang<-as.factor(c("English","Chinese","Korean","German"))
contrasts(lang)
contrastmatrixlang<-cbind(cbind(c(1.414215,0,0,-1.414214), c(-0.816497,1.632993,0,-0.816497)),c(-0.57735,-0.57735,1.73205,-0.57735)) # orthogonal coding for 4-level factors, see Kuhfeld 1997
contrasts(lang)<-contrastmatrixlang
marital<-as.factor(c("Single","Married"))
contrastmatrixmarital<-c(1,-1) # orthogonal coding for 2-level factors
contrasts(marital)<-contrastmatrixmarital
children<-as.factor(c("none","one","two"))
contrastmatrixchildren<-cbind(c(1.224745,0,-1.224745),c(-0.707107,1.414214,-0.707107)) # orthogonal coding for 3-level factors
contrasts(children)<-contrastmatrixchildren
cand.list<-expand.grid("Language" = lang, "Marital Status" = marital, "Children" = children)
formula=~`Language`+`Marital Status`+`Children`+`Marital Status`:`Children`
library(AlgDesign)
set.seed(1337)
optB<-optBlock(frml=formula, withinData=cand.list, blocksizes=c(12,12))
set.seed(1337)
optF<-optFederov(frml=formula, data=cand.list, nTrials=12)
optB$D
# [1] 1
optF$D
# [1] 0.8735807
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. In case anyone struggles with this in the future, here's how the standardized orthogonal contrast coding can be calculated:

To calculate the orthogonal coding, you'll need a column with 1s for the intercept and with the effects coding that is provided by `contr.sum`. Those two need to be combined to a matrix. After this, all you need to do is orthonomarlize the matrix for example by using `orthonormalize` of the `far` library (available from CRAN). In orthonormalized matrix if you calculate the sum of the square of a column, the result will be 1. In case of the standardized orthogonal contrast coding you actually want the columns sum of squares to be n where n is the number of factor-levels. So all you need to do is multiply the orthonormalized matrix by the square root of n. The last step is to remove the first column.

Example for a factor with n=6:

```
library(far)
ex <- as.factor(c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
EC <- cbind(c(1,1,1,1,1,1), contr.sum(ex))
SOCC <- orthonormalization(EC)*6^(1/2)
SOCC <- SOCC[,(2:6)]
contrasts(ex) <- SOCC
```

Which results in:

```
contrasts(ex)
       [,1] [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
A  1.732051   -1 -0.7071068 -0.5477226 -0.4472136
B  0.000000    2 -0.7071068 -0.5477226 -0.4472136
C  0.000000    0  2.1213203 -0.5477226 -0.4472136
D  0.000000    0  0.0000000  2.1908902 -0.4472136
E  0.000000    0  0.0000000  0.0000000  2.2360680
F -1.732051   -1 -0.7071068 -0.5477226 -0.4472136
```